# how to fix instance based nill problem plezase

Tags: gd

```
extends Node2D

@onready var timer = $Timer


var obstacle = preload("res://enviroment/obstacle.tscn")


func _ready():
    randomize()
func _on_timer_timeout():
    spawn_obstacle()

func spawn_obstacle():
    var obstacle = obstacle .instance()
    add_child(obstacle)
    obstacle.position.y = randi()%400+150
    
func start():
    timer.start()
func stop():
    stop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQP8j.png)

g*nothing*bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb